# select element set different names than from API

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Need some help regardin material ui select element & naming dropdown, questions:

1: My api where i populate dropdown does not have good names, is it possible to give some names to those, without me going to my api and add name to every of them ?

can i some how add a code where names in dropdown are like this , data 1, data 2, data 3...

at the moment i have set it to '{option.label}' which comes from my an array of object, so is there a way to set name 'data 1, data 2, data 3...' without me editing my array(it could be hundreds of lines) ?

2:  as you can see from image, i have set backgound color but it doesnt affect that part, why ?

3: input label name is at the top of select, how to drop it to inside ?

I searched from stackoverflow and did not find answer to these, so i asked all three question here. English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-bpu71w?file=/demo.js

[image]

code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import "./Tama.css";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [dataa, setData] = React.useState("twny");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setData(event.target.value);
  };

  const data = [
    {
      value: "USD",
      label: "$"
    },
    {
      value: "EUR",
      label: "€"
    },
    {
      value: "BTC",
      label: "฿"
    },
    {
      value: "JPY",
      label: "¥"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Box sx={{ m: 1 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select value={dataa} onChange={handleChange} className="ok">
          {data.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem
              className="menuItem"
              onClick={() => console.log("Chosen: ", option.label)}
              key={option.value}
              value={option.value}
            >
              {option.label}
              <button
                className="menuItem__button"
                onClick={() => console.log("Clicked: ", option)}
              >
                Edit
              </button>
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

```css
.menuItem {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #1e2328;
  color: red;
}

.menuItem__button {
  margin-left: 90%;
}

#demo-simple-select-label {
  color: red;
}

.ok {
  background-color: #1e2328;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: any help/advice is appreciated !

Comment: Question 2,3 Did you opened the inspector to see what is going on ? For the label's position you set position: absolute AND position: relative and for the background color you set padding: 0 then padding top AND bottom to 8px;

Comment: these problems you have almost has nothing to do with react, the problem is, it seems you don't know enough html/css and JS, so try to learn them first before using React. It's a must to know them before using React.

Answer (score 0):

1- it's not good idea you have to update list value from your api

2- for background issue use this:

```
.MuiList-root {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #1e2328;
  color: red;
}
```

3- for input label issue use `variant="outline"` to hide label in input

```
<InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" variant="outline">Age</InputLabel>
```

Comment: 1: API where i am getting the data, has not good names, isnt there any way to put random names ? 3: vriant outline just removes it, but i want to have it inside select, when user jas not yet clicked select element, it should be inside select rather than at the top of it.

Comment: use `variant="standard"` take a look at  https://mui.com/components/selects/

Comment: 2: this works if i use externass css, but i am using makeStyles of material ui core, could you give an answer using that ?

Comment: I have no idea ,but it's good idea to modify it in externals css